# How can I display different content on a screen larger than 17 inches?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, screen

I have a wordpress website and I have content on the main page of my site.

When I open my website on a larger screen it does not look as good, and 17 inches is the largest screen size that makes my content look acceptable.

I want to display different content for screen sizes like 19, 20, 21, 22,etc inches.

My website is : https://hughesjobs.net

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: you can use media queries in your CSS for this, however it will be dependent on the resolution rather than the size of the screen

Comment: Dunno, inches is a valid measure in CSS I think so it might work.- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: You could use css media queries. You could use javascript if you want to as well- not quite as elegant as media queries. You could also detect device with javascript - not really recommended though.

Comment: what exact resoulution should I use for screen sizes over 17 inches

Comment: Just expand your browser and look the resolution when you feel  you need to change the content (chrome dev tools can give you the resolution of your viewport)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS Media Queries to add specific styling for elements at those specific screen sizes. However, I would recommend using something other than inches as your measurement. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length):

> For low-dpi devices, the unit px represents the physical reference
>   pixel and the others are defined relative to it. Thus, 1in is defined
>   as 96px which equals 72pt. The consequence of this definition is that
>   on such devices, length described in inches (in), centimeters (cm),
>   millimeters (mm) doesn't necessary match the length of the physical
>   unit with the same name.
>
> For high-dpi devices, inches (in), centimeters (cm), millimeters (mm)
>   are defined as their physical counterparts. Therefore the px unit is
>   defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).

Furthermore:

> The unit in doesn't represent a physical inch on screen, but
>   represents 96px. That means that whatever is the real screen pixel
>   density, it is assumed to be 96dpi. On devices with a greater pixel
>   density, 1in will be smaller than 1 physical inch. Similarly mm, cm,
>   and pt are not absolute length.
>
> Some specific examples:
>
> ```
> 1in is always 96px,
> 3pt is always 4px,
> 25.4mm is always 96px.
> ```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

**Update**

Here's an example of how to use a media query to target screen sizes greater than 19 inches (reminder: I do not suggest using inches in media queries):

```
@media all and (min-width: 19in) {
  #header {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

In the above example, the element with the id 'header' will be hidden when the screen width is above 19 inches (or equivalent).

For more on Media Queries:

- [MDN: CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
- [Google: Use CSS media queries for responsiveness](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en)
- [CSS3 Media Queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)

Comment: Ok, So how would I code the media query for bigger screen sizes like 19 inches.... can you give a example ... When I use the bigger screen size @media  wouldn't both content still be displayed?

Comment: @chris I added an example as well as more reference resources in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add media query in your style sheet as bellow example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1920px) {
 #content{
    /* Your style */    
  }

}
```